# How to convert a txt file into array in Java so I can deal with every array separately

Tags: java, arrays, text, type-conversion

I have a txt file containing somes numbers with a space between each 9 numbers. For example : `853617639 975336865`.
I exported the file using this code :

```
import java.io.*; 
public class ReadingFromFile { 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  { 
      try {
            FileReader fichierALire = new FileReader("Test.txt");
            int c = fichierALire.read();
            while (c != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) c);
                c = fichierALire.read();
                }
            fichierALire.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("There's a mistake with: " + exception.getMessage());


        }
      }}
```

Now, I need to convert this file into an array to manage the output. I want to see if, in the first 9 numbers, one number is repeated twice or more and if so, I want to replace it by a number who hasn't been used. Then, I want to do the same for the other batch (the last 9 numbers).

My first step would be to convert the txt file into an array, but I didn't find a way that would give me the output : `{8,5,3,6,1,7,6,3,9,9,7,5,3,3,6,8,6,5}`

When I'll find a way to have this output, I'll then have to create a code to see if there's a `int` that is repeated in the first 9 `int` and then modify it so it respect the condition I said above.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: How does the text file look? Does it have a single line or several ones? Why are not using `java.nio` for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your files looks like this:

> 23213461 2136487236 2873648723 28734682 3674324
>   92341286 8726387462 2837467364 376427863473

But this would also work for a file like this:

> 2376487234 sjdhfkajsdh kjsd65fs765df hjdsf js587 df sdkjf6f6f6f6f
>   6f6f6 6f f6 f6 6sdf

If you're using Java 8, you can stream the file line by line and split each line on the empty string. Then you can check if each substring (one character) is an integer. If it is, add it to your ArrayList `nums`, which you can convert to an array when you're done if you like. If it's a whitespace or a string - do nothing.

Now you can handle your logic with your `nums` array however you like.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(new File("yourFilePath/file.txt").toPath())
            .forEach(l -> addToMyArray(l.split("")));

        System.out.println(nums);
    }

    public static void addToMyArray(String[] arr) {
        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                nums.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```